# Can I access my protected method from a sub-class by using super keyword I need an explaination

Tags: java

### A.java

```
class A {
    protected void msg(){
        System.out.println("-------------------asdfghjkl");
    }
}
```

### B.java

```
class B extends A {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B obj = new B(); 
        obj.msg();
    }

    void dis() {
        super.msg();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

**Explanation**: That's according to Language specification. if you want to access a method of base class in derived class, mark that method as `protected` then using `super` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass can access the non-private members of its superclass as if they belong to the subclass itself. You do not need to use super in your example.
Super is aptly used in case of constructor calls, method overriding or in case where subclass hides any superclass member.

[image: Class member access from a subclass]